# selecting a particular field from a table?

Tags: php, sql, resultset

I am using the following SQL query:

```
Select * from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.id = t2.col
```

but my problem is that both the tables have fields with same name, `place`.
So how can I select the column with name `place` from `table2` in my PHP code?
I want to use the following php code

```
 while($row_records = mysql_fetch_array($result_records))
    {

            <?  echo $row_records['place']; ?>

     }
```

How can I fetch the field from particular table?

Comment: And zero answers, and zero votes!

Comment: @OP - it's OK if you don't have the confidence/experience to answer others' questions, but at least have the courtesy to up-vote helpful responses and select the answers that you feel have been most helpful. Currently, you are simply leeching...

Comment: @ all helpfull people:I am sorry as i had not accpeted any answers before.That was becoz i dint know how to accpet it and i also did not know that there is a way i can.I just posted a new question on how to accept an answer and i am not accpeting the answers as well as upvoting.
Sorry once again and thanks .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never use...

```
Select * from ...
```

... in a production environment - Always specify explicitly which columns you want to return.

Thus you could amend your SQL to:

```
Select t1.Place as T1Place, t2.Place as T2Place
  from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.id = t2.col
```

So in your PHP you would have:

```
 while($row_records = mysql_fetch_array($result_records))
 {

        <?  echo $row_records['T2Place']; ?>

 }
```

Comment: It perhaps matters less with dynamic languages; it mattered intensely with languages like COBOL, but the advice is still sound. Suppose the table is altered to add 3 extra fields: a picture, a movie clip, and a PDF file. Your query does not use any of them  but your code now pays the cost of transferring 3 monstrous (multi-megabyte) field values only to ignore them. It's funny: the users are now complaining about the performance of your application.  If you had not written the lazy 'SELECT *', you would not have suffered the indignity of having to go back and fix up your bodged up lazy code.

Comment: @Hop - Jonathan has explained one good reason; another is clarity. However, I'm genuinely open to alternative scenarios...

Comment: thanks for all the answeres and comments i just accpeted it and also upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the table alias and the field name.
For example,

```
    Select t1.place as t1_place, t2.place as t2_place 
      from table1 as t1, table2 as t2 where t1.id = t2.col
```

In your PHP code you can select it using

```
while($row_records = mysql_fetch_array($result_records))
    {
    echo $row_records['t1_place']; 
    echo '<br />';
    echo $row_records['t2_place']; 
    }
```